# Is there a way to add board from Arduino board manager to CLion Arduino plugin?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, clion

I have a LOLIN D1 mini board and i want to use CLion with it. I am able to add this board to Arduino IDE and work with it using this URL: http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json and Arduino IDE boards manager.
But CLion Arduino plugin has only default boards. Is there a way to add other boards to CLion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this you. You need to manually specify the boards.txt file in arduino plugin settings.

[image]

Then CLion will show desired boards on Arduino project creation.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You needs to add your board configuration into boards.txt file. Not sure what os you use for your computer, for Mac on my machine, it is at `~/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/`.

Comment: I use Mac as well. boards.txt at ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3 seems to have board configuration. It starts with: d1_mini_lite.name=LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 mini Lite . It is presented in Arduino IDE. But CLion still shows only default Arduino boards.